# Postfix, Dovecot Virtual Mail Server Unable to Restrict Access Different Hostname for SMTP, IMAP & POP3

Tags: linux, postfix, dovecot

I want to restrict access for SMTP for smtp.example.com, IMAP for imap.example.com & POP3 for pop3.example.com for my own mail server which i am building using POSTFIX & Dovecot i tried different ways and documentation but unable to do this all domains are accessible all services on the same server whole setup is on the same server not on different.

How this can be possible to restrict access for service on specific domain/hostname?

Comment: Your question is entirely unclear. What do you mean by "all domains are accessible all services"?

Comment: I have mail server i am running roundcube at mail.exmaple.com, Postfix Admin at padmin.example.com, there other subdomains associated with same ip on same server smtp.example.com, pop3.example.com and imap.example.com for SMTP, POP3 and IMAP access out side the server. So i want to restrict access each service against their subdomain. Currently through all subdomains i can access smtp, pop3 and imap i tried the address listening in dovecot and postfix but not working. Hope you got my point.

Comment: Why do you want to set it up like this in the first place? It has absolutely no benefit. The applications don't care if they connect to pop3.exampl.com, imap.example.com, or mail.example.com. Using a single subdomain for all services makes the configuration even easier. Separating the subdomain makes IMO only sense when you have the services running on different hosts anyway.

Comment: Yes, i know single domain makes the setup easier basically i am building my own server and practicing thats why need to be clear about this separate implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in the IMAP, POP or SMTP protocol as these protocols do not advise the server the domain they are connecting to - The client simply resolves the domain to an IP and connects to that.

This means that you will need to assign different IP addresses for each domain name, and then somehow filter access based on that. At this point you may find it easiest to run multiple VMS or containers as Postfix and Dovecot aren't build with this in mind.  (Indeed its unclear to me why you would do this anyway).

I do note that you can set up virtual hosting so the full email address is used for sending and receiving email, which allows you to have the same user at different domains with different credentials. (If you are trying to do this you have asked the wrong question)

Comment: Thanks for the clearance the other things i setuped and working fine mails sending and receiving just i was not confirmed about the postfix and dovecot they are only resolve to IP not domain.